# Looking for a LaTeX resource library

Tags: external-files, database

I'm a teacher, writing different kinds of documents with a lot of **cultural resources** that I have to organise with a catalog, then filter to retrieve ressources I want to import into my document, and fanialy **integrate or link into different Latex documents**. For bibliographic material I can use **bibtex**. It's ok. But as I know, bibtex only store refences, not media files (picture, video, audio file, etc.).

Furthemor I would like the ressource libray store also pieces of latex code (latex grain content or latex beans if you know what I mean), in order to manage an exercices database. Each latex beans may use media files (pictures, etc.). Then I would like to import this pieces of latex code into my document, like a citation (verbatim) or like a template import (I could use parameters to specify the content of the latex piece of code)...

I know [TeXoMaker](https://github.com/Domlol/texomaker) could be a solution. But it looks a little simplistically... Does it work with all media files ? And does it suit for huge catalog with categories or other index fields to organise the content ? Furthemore, at this time I can't compile it *(I'm using Linux Debian and there I need a dev package wich is no longer into Debian wheezy repository)*.

I know also [citavi](https://www.citavi.com/fr/) but my version is only running with Windows and I would use Linux Debian. And the import to Latex is not supoprted, nevertheless it could be a first tool to manages madias ressources, and support knowledge base too.

About [JabRef](http://jabref.sourceforge.net) it is especialy a reference manager, not a ressource database to store media files. I understand I could reference a document into latex, but not include the document itself. And you can't get a previw for pictures, you need to open the picture into externa graphic program. It's not suitable to look visualy for a picture.

About EndNote : It is not running under linux.

I know I could build my own database. But It's dificult and taking a lot of time. I'm telling myself I'm not the first to be interested in this sort of resource catalog, so may be the wheel is already running ...

**So do you know others alternatives tools to catalog Latex and media files resources ? *(free of charge or not, with Latex integration or not)***

Comment: I wouldn't say LaTeX and friends are great for cataloging things, though they can be useful for producing the catalog ... so I'm not sure what you have in mind. BibTeX is a good choice "for" cataloging, I think. How should "texomaker" (= texmaker?) work "with" media files? It is easy to install other *TeX-related files so that your distribution can find them. What do you mean you can't install it? (Is it a permission thing?).

Comment: @jon I don't think so. I think the OP means TeXoMaker, as they say. I've added a link which seems to be right for the github page.

Comment: However, I don't really know what it is for or what the OP wants to catalogue. What does cataloguing *LaTeX* refer to? And what kind of media resources?

Comment: @cft -- Ah, OK. I thought catching a possible typo was the easy part, but  I've never used Texmaker or (obviously) TeXoMaker so I think I'm well out of my depth here.

Answer (score 1):

I found myself a part of my response : it's [**datatooltk**](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/datatooltk). It look's good to produce latex library pieces of code and building templates to include this material into documents. But it could'nt to store media files ressources into the database. So, I have to store them into the file system. May be there is a solution to register into a project folder and include this medias files with relative path into datatooltk latex code...

I found also [**probsoln**](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/probsoln), a toool specific to build exercices database. There is a link with datatooltk...

Answer (score 1):

Digging up an old topic here, but you could give TeXamator a try:

http://alexisfles.ch/en/texamator/texamator.html

https://www.linux-apps.com/p/1127989/

It works a little bit like TeXomaker except you don't have to build a database first : it will go through all your .tex files and look for, well, almost whatever you want it to.